# SKPhysicBodies appear to be slightly off-place

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

**Edit:** I have  been able to solve this problem by using PhysicsEditor to make a polygonal physicsbody instead of using `SKPhysicsBody(... alphaThreshold: ... )`

--

For some reason I'm having trouble with what I'm assuming is SKPhysicBodies being slightly off-place. While using `showPhysics` my stationary obstacle nodes appear to have their physicbodies in the correct position, however I am able to trigger collisions without actually touching the obstacle. If you look at the image below it shows where I have found the physicsbodies to be off centre, despite `showPhysics` telling me otherwise. (Note, the player node travels in the middle of these obstacle nodes).

[image]

I also thought it would be worth noting that while the player is travelling, its physicbody appears to travel slightly ahead but I figured this is probably normal.

I also use `SKPhysicsBody(... alphaThreshold: ... )` to create the physicbodies from .png images.

Cheers.

Edit: Here's how I create the obstacle physicbodies. Once they're added into the worldNode they are left alone until they need to be removed. Apart from that I don't change them in any way.

```
let obstacleNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ... )
obstacleNode.position = CGPoint(x: ..., y: ...)
obstacleNode.name = "obstacle"

obstacleNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: obstacleNode.texture!, alphaThreshold: 0.1, size: CGSize(width: obstacleNode.texture!.size().width, height: obstacleNode.texture!.size().height))
obstacleNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
obstacleNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
obstacleNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CC.wall.rawValue
obstacleNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = CC.player.rawValue
obstacleNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CC.player.rawValue

worldNode.addChild(obstacleNode)
```

The player node is treated the same way, here is how the player moves.

```
playerNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
```

Comment: You should include your code so we can see where the issue is coming from.

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: are these sprites moving by chance?  It is possible for your physicsbody to be ahead of your graphics because the draw phase did not happen yet

Comment: Yeah the player node is moving. I figured that was the case, however the obstacles are stationary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you aren't showing the exact images that you used to create your `SKSpriteNode` and `SKPhysicsBody` instances. Since you are using a texture to define the shape of your `SKPhysicsBody` you are likely running up against this:

[SKPhysicsBody documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody)

> If you do not want to create your own shapes, you can use SpriteKit to create a shape for you based on the sprite’s texture.

This is easy and convenient but it can sometimes give unexpected results depending on the textures you are using for your sprite. Perhaps try making an explicit mask or using a simple shape to represent your physics body. There are very good examples and guidelines in that documentation.

I would also follow this pattern when you set the properties on your objects:

```
// safely unwrap and handle failure if it fails
guard let texture = obstacleNode.texture else { return } 

// create the physics body
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, 
                                alphaThreshold: 0.1, 
                                size: CGSize(width: texture.size().width, 
                                             height: texture.size().height))

// safely set its properties without the need to unwrap an Optional
physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false

// set the rest of the properties

// set the physics body property on the node
obstacleNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
```

By setting the properties on a concrete instance of `SKPhysicsBody` and fully unwrapping and testing `Optionals` you minimize the chances for a run-time crash that may be difficult to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will look into this now